# I am trying to build a countdown timer. And the width update is pushing the footer down when mobile toggle is on

Tags: html, css

You have this pen here.

https://codepen.io/iwaduarte/pen/mdJvaLj

The thing is you can **NOT** reproduce the error **unless** you copy it and test locally in your own browser.

Every time that I alter the  type of view (from desktop to mobile) the footer section gets pushed down. It adds an unnecessary: **height?**

So if you hit the `Toggle device toolbar` (Chrome) in the `Inspection tools` you will see that the `<footer>` gets pushed down.

Why is that happening? I know it is overflowing the X-axis but why is adding a scrollbar while in **"mobile mode"**?

Is that a bug? How to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

> Is that a bug? How to solve that?

<s>It seems to me that the absence of the `viewport` meta info causes this problem. Since the CSS `fixed` property makes an element to get positioned relative to the view port, by default the standard mobile device height is taken as reference `viewport` (e.g. Pixel 2 has `411x731px`).---</s>

In order to prevent something like this from happening you should provide the `viewport` meta info in the `head`, a la:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

> @comment: It is not causing the problem. My local index.html has this
>   tag.

I think, I found the cause. Looks like you have to set `overflow` to `auto` (default is `visible`) for the `html` and `body`. It should work. I just tested on my mobile phone (should have done it before posting my answer first).

Checkout this example, and give me feedback whether and how this works for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <style>
    .bot-footer {
      background-color: #59e01b;;
      color: white;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      font-size: 3vw
    }

    html, body {
      overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <hr style=" width: 3000px;"/>
    <footer class="bot-footer">Like at least </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not causing the problem. My local index.html has this tag. Please review your answer

Comment: @iwaduarte sorry, I really thought this is the cause. Let me check if I can find a solution.

Comment: @iwaduarte you are right. I striked the wrong part. But I think it has something to do with the behaviour of `fixed` property [regarding the viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and also with the vertical `viewport` height which AFAIK can't be set as per device height. So, if in case html and body have `overflow: visible`, `position: fixed` apparently tends to take the actual device height as viewport-height - that's what I am saying...

Comment: That error **does not** appear in the normal view whereas the viewport is higher or smaller (if you resize the window manually). So I guess there is nothing to do with the fixed property.

Comment: @iwaduarte Hm, weird. Thanks for the feedback! I'm out of answers now. It needs more debugging.

Comment: @iwaduarte in any case the width of `<hr>` and thus horizontal scrolling seems to cause this weird behaviour (again idk why), but if you put the overflowing parts into a container that has `overflow: auto`, then this problem doesn't occur, e.g. `<div style="overflow: auto"><hr style=" width: 3000px;"/></div>`

Comment: I got that part. The problem is related to the container itself expanding with the <hr> tag, I do not know if that is desired. If you set a width the problem is gone.